# Android widget how can get time in hour and minute from this?

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager

In my App, I created widgets to show the time in analog clock format. When click on widget actually showing alarm class to set the alarm for that widget and its also working fine.

For that I used this code:

when click on widget I call this one in update and getting alarm class from this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context, 0, getAlarmPackage(context), 0);
rv_ana.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.clock, pendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv_ana);
```

and alarm function method:

```
public Intent getAlarmPackage(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent AlarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    String clockImpls[][] = {
            { "Standard Alarm", "com.android.alarmclock",
                    "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock" },
            { "HTC Alarm ClockDT", "com.htc.android.worldclock",
                    "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl" },
            { "Standard Alarm ClockDT", "com.android.deskclock",
                    "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock" },
            { "Froyo Nexus Alarm ClockDT", "com.google.android.deskclock",
                    "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock" },
            { "Moto Blur Alarm ClockDT", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock",
                    "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock" },
            { "Samsung Galaxy S", "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage",
                    "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage" } 
    };

    boolean foundClockImpl = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < clockImpls.length; i++) {
        String packageName = clockImpls[i][1];
        String className = clockImpls[i][2];
        try {
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
            packageManager.getActivityInfo(
                        cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            AlarmClockIntent.setComponent(cn);    
            foundClockImpl = true;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException nf) {
        }
    }
    if (foundClockImpl) {
        return AlarmClockIntent;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But my requirement is from this alarm function how can I get time in hours and time in minutes. Actually that function automatically shows the alarm but I want to know the time.
Is it possible or not? Help me?

Comment: After reading your question two times, I still don't know what you want. If you want to know the current time, you can use `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` and the like.

Comment: So you want the Alarm time back to your widget from the alarm application?

Comment: I have also read the question numerous times and I'm not clear what you want. Do you want the code you've posted to have access to the actual time, or the time show on the widget? Or the MAIN that is launched by the Intent?

Comment: confusing, indeed. he got 3 upvotes, though... :)

Comment: I don't want time from the calender. U know how to set alarm from the os supported package as shown above. From above case we have to set alarm directly to the widget according my code through settings. But i want to get the time from that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You If you want the alarm time you can use this.

```
String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```

then convert it to Date.

```
String string = nextAlarm;//Tue 8:30"
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: the code which is posted above same as like me that's also working for me.in that when we set up alarm its working fine. How can we get time in hours and minutes from that above code.

Comment: No.. Actually we set one time in alarm that time i want to get through programmaing.

Comment: Time left for alarm or alarm time.

Comment: alarm timings in hours and minutes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29461/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-ayush)